# JMeter Json Extraction of random not null values

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using below JSON Extractor to extract random ItemID which is not null.
$..[ ? ( @ .ItemID != null)].ItemID

It extracts random ItemID but also picks "null" value.
Can you please help me in this regard.

```
{
    "Items" : [
        {
            "ItemID": null,
            "deliveryId": "1",
        }, {
            "ItemID": "IT01",
            "deliveryId": "2",
        }, {
            "ItemID": "IT02",
            "deliveryId": "3",
        }, {
            "ItemID": "test",
            "deliveryId": "3",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant [JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query would be something like:

```
$.Items.[?(@.ItemID != null)].ItemID
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JsonPath Filter Operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)